Can't understand Nelmio Api Doc Annotations
I'm having trouble configuring the generation of API documentation using NelmioApiDocBundle with Symfony. I'm trying to add annotations to describe my routes, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.
I am required to use the #[...] format for annotations due to the version of Symfony I'm using, rather than the traditional /** ... */ format.
Here's the code for my controller:
#[Route('/badges', name: 'api_list_badges', methods: ['GET'])]
#[
    OA\Get(
        description: 'Lists all badges',
        summary: 'Lists all badges of all users',
        responses: [
            new OA\Response(
                response: 200,
                description: 'Success',
                content: new OA\JsonContent(ref: new Model(type: Badge::class), type: 'object')
            ),
            new OA\Response(response: 500, description: 'Internal Server Error'),
        ]
    )
]
public function getAll(){
    $badges = $this->badgeRepository->findAll();
    $data = $this->serializer->serialize($badges, 'json', ['groups' => 'list_badge']);
    return new JsonResponse($data, 200, [], true);
}

And here's my YAML configuration for NelmioApiDocBundle:
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: 'TEST'
            description: 'This is the API documentation.'
            version: '1.0.0'
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: ['^/api(?!/doc$)']
    models:
        use_jms: false
    use_validation_groups: true

I'm particularly confused about the following points:

Are the annotations in my code correctly formatted to be recognized by NelmioApiDocBundle?

Is there any additional configuration required to ensure the annotations are properly processed and included in the generated documentation?

Are there any specific options in my YAML configuration that I need to check to make sure the annotations are properly considered?


Thank you in advance for your help! Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

a good way to know if nelmioapidocbundle interpreted your annotations and/or attributes the way you intended, is to just view the documentation and check each endpoints. then if something isn't working, you can focus on that part. the single endpoint you added to your question looks good to me.

I think it looks good but my documentation don't show all the stuff I write in annotations. Responses and description are just empty in my doc... It detect my route because it start with "/api" but nothing I write is taken into account

I'm not sure about the description but for the response you should use new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Model() instead of Oa\JsonContent for an object (you can see examples on the documentation
#[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'Returns the rewards of an user',
    content: new OA\JsonContent(
        type: 'array',
        items: new OA\Items(ref: new Model(type: AlbumDto::class, groups: ['full']))
    )
)]

On the example above I took from the docs, you can the see the object itsself use new Model(type: '')
